# How to show current permissions of a folder

Tags: 10.04, server, permissions

I want to find out who has what permissions on a certain folder. How would I go about viewing this?

The folder in question is /srv/www

Comment: You have explained excellently @Octavian Damiean.In the GUI based property/permission setting most boxes are grayed out. and you cannot change them, is it because they were created by ROOT and the user is NON ROOT??

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On the command line you'd issue a `ls -la /srv/www`. The part that is interesting for you is the second line.

Explanation of all columns:

```
total [NUMBER]
[PERMISSIONS] [LINKS] [OWNER] [GROUP]  [FILE SIZE] [MODIFICATION DATE] [ITEM]
```

Sample output:

```
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 2011-04-13 13:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 2011-04-17 19:31 ..
```

Now the really interesting part for your is the line of the `.` element as that represents the current directory.

The permissions of the current directory in my sample `drwxr-xr-x` would mean the following:

- d for directory
- rwx means read, write and execute permissions for the owner
- r-x means read and execute permissions for the group
- r-x means read and execute permissions for all others

To get the permissions in the GUI you would

1. Right-click the directory you want to know the permissions of and select `Properties`.
2. Click on the `Permissions` tab to get this

   [image]

Answer (score 16):

You can also use:

```
ls -ld /path/to/directory
```

if you are only interested in the permissions of the directory and not its contents

Answer (score 0):

If you are running X then right click, properties, permissions tab... otherwise try 'ls -l' in the terminal